# Screen sharing SDK for Android not shares preview

Tags: android, camera, preview, screensharing, teamviewer

i tried teamviewer's screen sharing sdk, with a camera preview.
I have two questions.
1. , Is it possible to programmatically accept incoming connections?
2. , A camera preview not appears on the "second screen" just the rest of the layout, how to fix this?
Please help!

Regards,
Peter

Comment: Dude, where is the programming part in this question? you ought not ask these questions without making an effort yourself

Comment: Dude, "programmatically accept incoming connections" e.g. is a programming question, which i tried to understand myself by digging into the source code, i could found some view id (accept button, cancel button), but cant find the class that uses them, also dont know how to call it programmatically. 2 a camera preview thing : "...just the rest of the layout...", which means i also tried this one, and i dont know if the problem occures because of my mistake (my fault not to copy the source code here), or because of the screen sharing sdk limits.